# Covariance and contravariance

Tags: c#

May be my question is dumb but here it is.

Is Covariance and contravariance only applicables for delegates in c#?

Can we have Covariance and contravariance in normal class hierarchies?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is Covariance and contravariance only applicables for delegates in c#?

Not quite; the language-level variance can also apply to *interfaces*, for example `IEnumerable<out T>`
(likewise `in` is fine too).

I should also note that arrays of reference-types are also covariant:

```
string[] orig = {"abc","def"};
object[] sameArray = orig;
```

> Can we have Covariance and contravariance in normal class hierarchies?

No; it does not apply to classes / structs (although you can of course implement a covariant interface, and coerce to that interface).

Comment: Oops; I think I clicked the wrong button and deleted Brian's comment, but he correctly noted that arrays can be covariant too.

Comment: That is assignment compatability. there is a difference between covariance and assignment compatablility. check this erric lippert article. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/30/what-s-the-difference-between-covariance-and-assignment-compatibility.aspx

Comment: @Marc : Thanks for your answer but Do you have any idea why this limitation is ?

Comment: @Adeel - which, the arrays? no, it is covariance, as defined in the language spec; ECMA 334v4 §19.5; I don't have the MS spec reference to hand, but it should be similar.

Comment: Method group conversions are also co- and contravariant in C#.

Comment: @Eric - d'oh; I always miss that one

Comment: @MarcGravell Pardon my late remarks - but when you say co/ntra-variance does/doesn't apply to class hierarchy, what exactly are your referring to

IMO, A class hierarchy is implicitly covariant, meaning if class A extends class  B then it also extends any super-class (base) of B

Comment: @mho  that isn't really variance; I mean the "in"/"out" features of c# 4, which applies to generic interfaces and delegate types only.